# An introduction for integral tricks.

Tags: integration, soft-question, big-list

I wonder if there's a good book or internet page introducing integral tricks? 
For example integration by parts, and Feynman's trick.

I'm not looking for an exercise book such as "Problems in Mathematical Analysis " by Boris Demidovich.

I hope the introduction categorizes by problem type and recommend tricks. For example wiki page on Ordinary Differential Equations has a section "[summary of exact solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions)" that does not only provide the solution, but also the solution method, e.g. Separation of variables, Integrating factor, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would submit a vote for [The Handbook of Integration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0867202939).

It covers both numerical and analytic integrals. Off the top of my head, it includes techniques such as u-substitution, integration by parts, integral transforms (ie. Mellin, Laplace), Frullani integrals, integrals by differentiation under the integral sign and integration by special functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent book that looks very interesting: [Inside Interesting Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493912763) (2014). If you have access through SpringerLink, you can download it.

Comment: thanks @David , it does look interesting!